# How to read minute values greater than 60 and avoid ValueError: time data '60:01' does not match format '%M:%S'

Tags: python

I've a script that reads a corrupt .CUE file that has no INDEX 00 and retreives the minutes and seconds value of each track entry. When the values are found the script subtracts 02 seconds of each track (thus creating a pregap and correcting the .CUE file) and creates a new correct .CUE file. The script worked like a charm till it encountered .CUE files containing minute values greater than 60. The following error occured:

```
ValueError: time data '60:01' does not match format '%M:%S'
```

I used datetime because i couldn't just simply subtract the 02 secondes of each track entry as an integer. When an entry has an 'INDEX 01' seconds value of 01 seconds it will also affect the minute value when 02 seconds are subtracted since this means that the minute value will be reduced by 01.

This is part of the code that does the formatting and subtraction. This worked fine till it encountered a minute value than 60:

```py
from datetime import datetime

WrongIndex = '60:01'
NewIndex = '00:02'
format = '%M:%S'
time = datetime.strptime(WrongIndex, format) - datetime.strptime(NewIndex, format)
```

The expected returned value in this case should be '59:59'.

I'd like to know if there are other ways to use minute values greater than 60 since the max length of these files can go up to 79.8 minutes.

Comment: Convert them to maths !

Comment: Similar question using [regex to extract from e.g. "MMM:SS" with unlimited minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70919879/regex-mmss-unlimited-minutes-no-hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a `datetime` object is really an appropriate data structure for your problem. That type expects to be referencing a real clock time, not just an arbitrary number of minutes and seconds. If you were sticking with `datetime`, a more appropriate type would probably be `timedelta`, which represents a period of time, unmoored from any specific clock or calendar. But there's no equivalent to `strptime` for `timedelta`s.

And without the parsing, you don't get much from `datetime` at all. So I suggest just doing the parsing yourself. It's not very difficult:

```
minutes, seconds = map(int, WrongIndex.split(':'))
```

This just splits your input string (e.g. `'60:01'`) into a list with two values (`['60', '01']`). It then converts the string values into integers. Then it assigns the two integers to the variables `minutes` and `seconds`.

To make doing math easy, you can then combine the two values into a single integer, a count of seconds:

```
seconds += minutes * 60
```

Then you can subtract your two-second offset and convert the number of seconds back to a time string:

```
seconds -= 2    # or parse the offset string if you don't want to hard code two seconds

result = "{:02}:{:02}".format(*divmod(seconds, 60))
```

In the formatting step, I'm using the `divmod` function which computes the a floor division, and a modulus in one step (it returns both in a tuple).

Comment: Thank you very much! this did the trick. I accepted and upvoted the answer but my rep is too low to change the public score.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some converting. I would convert your values to integers. If minutes is greater than 59, we will add it to hours. After that we can create a datetime object which we use to subtract. To get minutes, we take our deltas in seconds and divided it with 60

```py
from datetime import datetime

def to_time(value):
    "Takes in values as '%M:%S' and return datetime object"

    # value casting to integers 
    minutes, seconds = [int(i) for i in value.split(':')]

    # if minutes is greater than 59 pass it to hour
    hour = 0
    if minutes > 59:
        hour = minutes//60
        minutes = minutes%60

    return datetime.strptime(f'{hour}:{minutes}:{seconds}', '%H:%M:%S')


# now our calculations 
wrong_index = '60:01'
new_index = '00:02'

time_ = to_time(wrong_index) - to_time(new_index)

print(time_.seconds/60)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but @Blckknght 's answer is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import datetime

WrongIndex = '60:01'
NewIndex = '00:02'

wrong_time =  WrongIndex.split(':')
new_index = NewIndex.split(':')

old_seconds = int(wrong_time[0])*60 + int(wrong_time[1])
new_seconds = int(new_index[0])*60 + int(new_index[1])

time = datetime.timedelta(seconds=old_seconds-new_seconds)
print(time)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but this will add hours to the mix, unfortunately those values are not present in a .CUE file.