# Regex MM:SS, unlimited minutes (no hours)

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm using some validation in Google Sheets but I need the total minutes and seconds in the following format for each dive.

E.g.

```
42:38 (42 minutes, 38 seconds)
62:35
85:26
```

I do not want hours to be an option; I only want to work with minutes and seconds, as this is then converted in the database separately.

I have seen the below on another form but have no idea where to start with regex:

```
^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)$
```

This gives HH:MM:SS (with HH being optional); I have tried to have a play around with it but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^(\d+):([0-5]?\d)$
```

Or, if `\d` is not supported as in POSIX ERE:

```
^([0-9]+):([0-5]?[0-9])$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s4rFlP/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `:` - a colon
- `([0-5]?\d)` - Group 2: a digit from `0` to `5` and then one digit
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: `^([0]\d|[1-5]\d):([0]\d|[1-5]\d)$` 
https://regex101.com/r/CeuKko/1